# Qt File dialog not opening in sandbox on Mac OS

Tags: macos, file, qt, sandbox

I have a Mac OS app developed in Qt. I used the following codes to launch the open and save file dialog box:

```
//opening
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
    tr("Open"), "", tr("*.ext"));

//saving
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,
    tr("Save"), "filename", tr("*.ext"));
```

The code works fine when the app is not sandboxed. But when I sandbox it for distribution on the Mac App Store, the code does not work. The app just freezes for a moment. Any help?

Comment: What Qt version you are using?

Comment: I downloaded the latest offline version for Mac which says QtSDK 1.2.1. When I installed it, on the About screen it says, Qt Creator 2.4.1 Based on Qt 4.7.4 (64 bit).

Comment: But what version do you use to compile your software.

Comment: Do you get any output on stdout?

Answer (score 1):

This article should be helpful http://www.digia.com/en/Blogs/Qt-blog/Pasi_Matilainen/Dates/2012/4/How-to-Publish-Qt-Applications-in-the-Mac-App-Store/

tldr;

You need to use Qt 4.8.1 to publish into Mac App Store

> Using file save dialogs in a sandbox
>
> The file save dialog requires a non-empty default filename to work
>   correctly inside a sandbox. You can supply a default filename to the
>   save dialog as follows:
>
> ```
> QString fileSavePath = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, "Save file", "default filename");
> ```
>
> Or if you create the dialog instance yourself:
>
> ```
> QFileDialog *fileSaveDialog = new QFileDialog(this);
> fileSaveDialog->setAcceptMode(QFileDialog::AcceptSave);
> fileSaveDialog->selectFile("default filename");
> ```
>
> File open dialogs do not require any special set-up to work correctly.

But I think you should read whole article so you won't miss anything

Comment: So you're probably not using Qt 4.8.1. There is event Qt 4.8.3 already. Update your framework

Comment: When I use the SDK to update, it says all the components are up-to-date but the compiler is still 4.8.1. I presume it's a bug and I have to update manually?

Comment: @Mika Add ` QMessageBox::information(NULL, QString(), QString::fromLatin1(qVersion()));` in your main after QApplication instance and tell me what it says.

Comment: maybe try upgrading to Qt 4.8.3

Answer (score 0):

In sandbox you must use `NSOpenPanel` and `NSSavePanel` in order to acquire rights for different files or directories.

Take a look at [Powerbox and File System Access Outside of Your Container](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW4).

Comment: The app is developed in Qt, so I will need Qt alternatives.